# How to fix this CSS validation error..?

Tags: css, filter

```
.file_input_hidden {
    font-size: 45px; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    -khtml-opacity: 0; 
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This is the code. When i run it in sortsite, CSS validation error is shown 6th line of the code (top: 0px;). 
I could not trace out the issue.
Is there any thing wrong in filters?
Please help me out in fixing this issue.

Comment: Should be -ms-filter: alpha(opacity=0); but you shouldn't need that unless you have to support IE6 (10 year old browser with less than 1% marketshare)

Comment: The code needs to support Ie 6 to Ie 9, Chrome, Firefox, safari and opera too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with the `top` rule. I think these will throw validation errors:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
-khtml-opacity: 0; 
-moz-opacity: 0;
```

CSS validation should be used only as a guide as not all the new CSS features are supported and it will not validate the prefixed rules. I would say you don't need to go over zealous with the validation. Your CSS is just fine.

Comment: Thank you. 
Is the filters need to be specified in any order or can be placed randomly?

Comment: You did it the recommended way ... the prefixed rules and IE code before the standard rule

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what “sortsite” is, but the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) (which is the only CSS checker with any degree of authoritativeness) reports the line with `filter` as erroneous. It also issues warnings about vendor extensions (which start with hyphen `-`, such as `-moz-opacity`; in this case they are useless, but harmless).

There is no way to silence the error message, because the Microsoft construct `filter: alpha(opacity=0)` violates generic CSS syntax, in addition to being browser-specific. Keep it if you like to support IE 8 and older, too.

Comment: you have mentioned filter: alpha(opacity=0) violates generic css syntax. Can you tell me clearly. Is that syntax wrong?

Comment: @Sandhya, yes, it is totally wrong as far as CSS specifications are considered, since the value is not of a form allowed in them. But it is the form you need to cover IE 8 and older. (Using `ms-filter` is not sufficient for this, and it’s rather pointless, since it’s just an alternative syntax introduced in IE 8.)